# Get rid of ANSI output for Azure Powershell tasks (PSCore) running on Hosted agents

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-pipelines, devops, ansi-escape

For our deployment pipelines in ADO we have a build server running Powershell 7 and a number of ADO (build) agents.

The release pipelines contain Azure Powershell tasks (5.x).
Since we use Powershell 7  (PSCore) we see ANSI output characters printed as-is:

```
2023-06-03T07:17:29.4554048Z [33;1mVERBOSE: Loading compiled helper C:\fgrqabuildagent1\_work\_tasks\AzurePowerShell_72a1931b-effb-4d2e-8fd8-f8472a07cb62\5.222.1\ps_modules\VstsTaskSdk\VstsTaskSdk.dll.[0m
2023-06-03T07:17:29.7739643Z [33;1mVERBOSE: Exporting function 'Find-Match'.[0m
2023-06-03T07:17:29.7740533Z [33;1mVERBOSE: Exporting function 'New-FindOptions'.[0m
2023-06-03T07:17:29.7741361Z [33;1mVERBOSE: Exporting function 'New-MatchOptions'.[0m
```

This output is hindering seeing the number of warnings in the overview of the deployment

**Questions:**
*What is the best / cleanest / easiest way to get this ANSI output characters?*

According to https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/17322 this ANSI output seems to be related to $PSStyle.OutputRendering setting.

The Azure Powershell task will start the script with a -NoProfile:

```
 ##[command]"C:\Program Files\PowerShell\7\pwsh.exe" -NoLogo -NoProfile -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Command ". 'C:\ ...
```

So I cannot solve this by setting $PSStyle.OutputRendering in the Powershell profile(s) on the build server ($PROFILE | Get-Member -Type NoteProperty ).

The Azure Powershell task does not seem to have an option to influence this behavior either.

But setting the $PSStyle.OutputRendering in each and every powershell script we have created seems not really the way forward.

so , again :
*What is the best / cleanest / easiest way to get this ANSI output characters?*

Best regards,
Herbert